# After get() of DocumentSnapshot, program is not executing next line in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Function1 and Function2 are not executed completely.

//Function1

```
Future<void> getUserDetails() async {
  
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc('aLhON9H3H1ZpZvUB4ISUrK45Hk93')
        .get();
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
            globalImagePath = documentSnapshot['imageURL'];
      }
  }
```

//Function2 (fetch data from subcollection of "users" collection

```
Future<void> fetchPunchinDetails() async {
  
    try {
      var result = await _users
          .doc(user!.uid)
          .collection('attendance')
          .where('outTime', isEqualTo: null)
          .get();

     String dayStart = result.docs[0]['inTime'];
      if (dayStart.isNotEmpty) {
        dayStarted = true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

// Calling above two methods

```
_fetchAndGotoScreens() {

    if (loginSuccess = true) {
      getUserDetails();   //--------calling Function1
      fetchPunchinDetails();  //----------calling Function2

     
        //Go to attendance page-----------
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                Attendance(imagePath: imagePath, dayStartTime: dayStartTime),
          ),
        )
            .catchError((e) {
          print(e);
        });
      } else {
        // go to home page------------
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHome()))
            .catchError((e) {
          print(e);
        });
      }
  
  }
```

When I step through, in getUserDetails() itself, it returns to the calling method just after executing .get(). It is not even checking if (documentSnapshot.exists) condition. The same happens with fetchPunchinDetails() function. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchPunchinDetails` and `getUserDetails` are future method, try using `await` before theses to complete.

```dart
_fetchAndGotoScreens() async{

    if (loginSuccess = true) {
     await getUserDetails();   
     await fetchPunchinDetails();
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)